# SSIS Lookup fails after removing output column

Tags: ssis, lookup

I am so close to snap out after two weeks of SSIS... it is SO FULL of bugs, that I cannot imagine how it could be launched... I forgot how much I hated it...

But, back to the problem:

I have a lookup (which is a work around for another bug, by the way) that works jsut fine. Upper on the flow I have a script component that adds some columns to a Output.

I will add some 2 of the columns from that output in another way, lower in the flow, so, I need to remove them from the script component. All good, except that if I do that, the lookup will not work anymore...will find no match... even if it does not use in ANY way any of those columns that I just removed...

It might be some synchronization problem, or, I don't know what, but I cannot seem to fix this stupid stupid thing. Does anyone have any ideea? Did this happened to you also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I have found SSIS complex to develop for (and downright annoying to troublshoot my own bugs), I really haven't found it to be particularly buggy. Perhaps it is your understanding of it that is buggy not the product itself.

I never use the script component to add columns, that's what the derived column task is for.

Without a better understanding of what your SSIS data flow looks like and is trying to do, it's kind of hard to provide any specific advice.